# Sellapp integration with React

Tags: html, reactjs, cdn

```
<head>
<script src="https://embed.sellpass.io/embed.js"></script>
</head>
```

The button only works if placed outside of react in index.html, doesn't work in a React component, nothing happens. That's unfortunate because my previous provider was working just fine.

```
<body>
<button
  data-sellpass-product-path="path"
  data-sellpass-domain="url">
  Purchase
</button>
```

I tried various tricks but none of them worked, so I'm asking for help.
UPDATE:
It only works in a React component when I refresh the page where that component is located.